# How to configure orangefs save the file into the same server, not split it?

Tags: file-io, filesystems

One of my friend tell me that orangefs could save the file into the same server and not split it, but i could not find any configuration info on http://docs.orangefs.com/configuration/admin_ofs_configuration_file/.

Does anybody know it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i find how to do it:
setfattr -n "user.pvfs2.num_dfiles" -v "1" /mnt/orangefs

reference:
http://www.orangefs.org/faq/#item6.6